# Error when outputting an image inside an embed with canvas | Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I have been getting this error when outputting an image using canvas (Node Module). Can anyone help?

```
embed.image.url: Could not interpret "{'name': 'welcome-image.png'}" as string.
```

I think this may be the issue here

```js
const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');
console.log("Testing 2")
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(member.tag)
  .setImage(attachment)
  .setFooter(client.config.footer)
  .setColor(client.config.color)
console.log("Testing 3")
return wChannel.send(embed);
```

If anyone could help me out here and try remove that error it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can't use an attachment as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#attaching-images) has the answer to your question. The way I do it with canvas is like this:

```js
var attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), `image_name.png`)
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(member.tag)
  .setFooter(client.config.footer)
  .attachFiles([attachment])
  .setImage(`attachment://image_name.png`)
  .setColor(client.config.color)
```